# LeetCode #1066 - Campus Bikes II

Tags: c++, algorithm

The following code implements the Hungarian algorithm. The algorithm is used to find minimum cost perfect matching on a bipartite graph.

Looking for comments on correctness, efficiency, clarity and idiomatic C++ usages. It passes all tests on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/campus-bikes-ii/).

```
class Solution
{
public:
    int assignBikes(vector<vector<int>>& workers, vector<vector<int>>& bikes)
    {
        if (workers.size() == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (bikes.size() == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        vector<vector<int>> costs;
        costs.resize(workers.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
        {
            costs[i].resize(bikes.size());
            for (int j = 0; j < bikes.size(); j++)
            {
                int wx = workers[i][0];
                int wy = workers[i][1];
                int bx = bikes[j][0];
                int by = bikes[j][1];
                int dx = wx - bx;
                int dy = wy - by;
                dx = dx > 0 ? dx : -dx;
                dy = dy > 0 ? dy : -dy;
                costs[i][j] = dx + dy;
            }
        }
        vector<pair<int, int>> answer = hungarian(costs);
        int result = 0;
        for (auto edge : answer)
        {
            result += costs[edge.first][edge.second];
        }
        return result;
    }
private:
    // Implementation of the Hungarian algorithm for finding a minimum cost perfect matching
    // The implementation is based on the description on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm
    vector<pair<int, int>> hungarian(const vector<vector<int>>& costs)
    {
        // The problem of finding a minimum cost assignment is the same as
        // finding the minimum cost perfect matching between the rows (workers) and the columns (jobs)
        int n = (int)costs.size();
        int m = (int)costs[0].size();

        // At all times, the algorithm maintains an integer named potential for all nodes.
        // The algorithm make sure potential(u) + potential(v) <= cost[u,v]
        // The nodes that represents the row are [0,n) and the nodes that represents the columns are [n, m + n)
        // Potential values are initialized to 0.
        vector<int> potential;
        potential.resize(m + n);
        for (int i = 0; i < m + n; i++)
        {
            potential[i] = 0;
        }

        // We maintain a directed graph, the edges of the graph is tight (i.e. potential(u) + potential(v) = cost[u,v]).
        // The edges from [n, m + n) back to [0, n) has to form a matching. (i.e. these edges does not share source/target)
        vector<vector<bool>> direction;
        direction.resize(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            direction[i].resize(m);
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                direction[i][j] = true;
            }
        }

        // If a node is involved in the matching, the matched flag will be true.
        vector<bool> matched;
        matched.resize(m + n);
        for (int i = 0; i < m + n; i++)
        {
            matched[i] = false;
        }

        // We will do a BFS to find paths. The parent array store the parent node used to discover a node.
        vector<int> parent;
        parent.resize(m + n);

        while (true)
        {
            queue<int> bfs;
            for (int i = 0; i < m + n; i++)
            {
                // Parent == -1 means it is not enqueued yet, so there is no parent
                parent[i] = -1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (!matched[i])
                {
                    bfs.push(i);
                    // Parent == -2 means it is enqueued because it is a not matched source node.
                    // It should NOT be enqueued again
                    parent[i] = -2;
                }
            }

            // This is just a standard BFS, note that the cost and direction array must be read from row to column
            while (bfs.size() > 0)
            {
                int visiting = bfs.front();
                bfs.pop();
                if (visiting < n)
                {
                    for (int neighbor = n; neighbor < m + n; neighbor++)
                    {
                        bool tight = costs[visiting][neighbor - n] - potential[visiting] - potential[neighbor] == 0;
                        if (direction[visiting][neighbor - n] && tight)
                        {
                            if (parent[neighbor] == -1)
                            {
                                bfs.push(neighbor);
                                parent[neighbor] = visiting;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int neighbor = 0; neighbor < n; neighbor++)
                    {
                        bool tight = costs[neighbor][visiting - n] - potential[visiting] - potential[neighbor] == 0;
                        if (!direction[neighbor][visiting - n] && tight)
                        {
                            if (parent[neighbor] == -1)
                            {
                                bfs.push(neighbor);
                                parent[neighbor] = visiting;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            bool found = false;
            for (int i = n; i < m + n; i++)
            {
                if (!matched[i] && parent[i] != -1)
                {
                    // If there is a way to reach from a source unmatched node to a target
                    // unmatched node, then we have an augmenting path, using the parent
                    // pointer chain, we can reverse all the paths to increasing the size
                    // of the matching by 1.
                    found = true;
                    int current = i;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (parent[current] == -2)
                        {
                            matched[i] = true;
                            matched[current] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        int small = min(current, parent[current]);
                        int large = max(current, parent[current]);
                        direction[small][large - n] = !direction[small][large - n];
                        current = parent[current];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                // If we cannot find an augmenting path, we will modify the potential
                // so that we have more nodes reachable from the unmatched sources
                int delta = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (parent[i] != -1)
                    {
                        for (int j = n; j < m + n; j++)
                        {
                            if (parent[j] == -1)
                            {
                                // Make sure the delta does not violate the constraint
                                // between each pair of reachable source/unreachable target
                                int margin = costs[i][j - n] - potential[i] - potential[j];
                                if (delta == -1 || margin < delta)
                                {
                                    delta = margin;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (delta == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (parent[i] != -1)
                    {
                        // For each reachable source, the potential is increased by delta
                        potential[i] += delta;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = n; i < m + n; i++)
                {
                    if (parent[i] != -1)
                    {
                        // For each reachable target, the potential is decreased by delta
                        potential[i] -= delta;
                    }
                }
                // After the manipulation:
                // The potential is feasible for reachable source, reachable target because the sum didn't change.
                // The potential is feasible for reachable source, unreachable target because the increase is checked earlier.
                // The potential is feasible for unreachable source, reachable target because the sum decrease.
                // The potential is feasible for unreachable source, unreachable target because the sum didn't change.
            }
        }
        vector<pair<int, int>> answer;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (!direction[i][j])
                {
                    answer.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

So in general the code is already quite good. It is well formated and easily readable.

From what I can see the most important task ahead is to familiarize yourself better with the stl and all the things it brings to the table:

1. Use qualified calls

   The habit of `using namespace std` is a vary bad one you should try to avoid as soon as possible. It doesnt really save you a lot and can get you in trouble quickly.
2. Use the appropriate member functions

   ```
   if (workers.size() == 0)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   This is technically correct and not even too bad performance wise for `std::vector`. However this is terrible for every other container. All containers feature a `empty()` method that should be used

   ```
   if (workers.empty())
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   The advantages are numerous. First you can never be too sure if `workers.size() == 0` is really correct. Did he mean `!= 0` or maybe `== 1` or whatever. With `empty` the intend is clear and there are only two possible cases which are often quite obvious to check. Also for any non-continuous container e.g `std::unorderd_set`, `std::set`, `std::forward_list` and `std::list` the determination of `size` requires a full traversal of the container. In contrast `empty` only checks a single pointer. So it is considerable cheaper.
3. Know the constructors

   The elements in the standard containers are value constructed

   ```
   vector<int> potential;
   potential.resize(m + n);
   for (int i = 0; i < m + n; i++)
   {
       potential[i] = 0;
   }
   ```

   Is equivalent to this

   ```
   vector<int> potential(m + n);
   ```

   If you have a certain value in mind you can also write it more explicitely as

   ```
   vector<int> potential(m + n, 0);
   ```

   This also works for nested containers so instead of

   ```
   vector<vector<bool>> direction;
   direction.resize(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       direction[i].resize(m);
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
       {
           direction[i][j] = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   We can write

   ```
   vector<vector<bool>> direction(n, std::vector<bool>(m, true));
   ```
4. Try to enforce const correctness

   I know this can seem like a lot of clutter but always mark constants as const so code like

   ```
   bool tight = costs[visiting][neighbor - n] - potential[visiting] - potential[neighbor] == 0;
   if (direction[visiting][neighbor - n] && tight)
       ...
   ```

   Should be written as

   ```
   const bool tight = costs[visiting][neighbor - n] - potential[visiting] - potential[neighbor] == 0;
   if (direction[visiting][neighbor - n] && tight)
       ...
   ```

   There is a great talk by [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Hb-9TUyjoo) about it. In a nutshell you want to convey as much information as possible, so that any variable that is *not* `const` sticks out
5. Do not build mountains

   There is only one occurence of it but try to avoid writing canyons like

   ```
   for (...) {
       if (condition) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   In this example there is only one level of identation but from personal expirience I can tell you that these mountains grow. Instead use early returns/continues

   ```
   for (...) {
       if (!condition) {
           continue;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   This greatly improves readability if there are multiple nested conditions and also makes is much clearer what is a precondition and what not.
6. Know you algorithms

   The stl offers a great variety of algorithms. There are numerous cases where you could use `std::accumulate` or `std::copy_if`. Try to learn those algorithms by heart. In general you can assume that the algorithms of the standard library are better tested and more performant that what you or I could cook up